# How to call javascript function when a new item is added to a specific list?

Tags: 2010, list, javascript

I would like to give user some notification with the ID of the item on status bar when a new item is added to a list, so far I got the javascript code for display text in status bar, but I don't know how to determine when the item is added to the list and how to get ID of the item.

What I want is something like this:

```
 <script>
 if(mylist.itemJustAdded ==true){
   fn_appendStatusBar(mylist.itemJustAdded.ID);
 }
 </script>
```

I already have fn_appendStatusBar(), but, how do I properly construct this if statement condition?

Comment: depends on where you are adding the new item, from a list webpart?

Comment: Are you adding a new item using list's oob form or you have made a custom form in which you have javascript code to add an item

Comment: @Mike sorry for late response, I'm adding item from list webpart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using NewForm.aspx**

If you are using the default new form to add items to the list, add the following javascript on the page you're redirecting to.

```
function getLastItemID(){
var queryBuffer = [];
queryBuffer.push("<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' LookupId='TRUE' /><Value Type='User'>"+_spUserId+"</Value></Eq></Where>");
queryBuffer.push("<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy>");
var res = spjs_QueryItems({listName:thisListGuid,query:queryBuffer.join(''),viewFields:['ID'],rowLimit:1});
if(res.count<0){
        alert("An error occurred. Most likely the parameter \"thisListGuid\" is wrong.");
}
else if(res.count>0){
return res.items[0].ID;
}else{
return '';
}
}
```

Usage:

```
var id= getLastItemID();
if(id)
fn_appendStatusBar(id);
```

Note: 
 
1. Replace `thislistGuid` with the listName or GUID. 
2. You need to download spjs-utility.js and refer it in your javascript. You can find it here: [spjs-utility.js](http://spjsfiles.com/index.php?dir=SharePoint%20JavaScripts%2Fspjs-utility%2F)
Source: [spjsblog](http://spjsblog.com/2011/04/23/redirect-from-newform-to-dispform-or-editform/)

---

**Using Custom Form**

If you are using a custom form, you can get the ID when you're adding the item to the list:

```
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var webSite = clientContext.get_web();
var lists = webSite.get_lists();
var testList = lists.getByTitle("TestList");
var itemCreationInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
var listItem = testList.addItem(itemCreationInfo);
listItem.set_item("bla", "bla");
listItem.update();
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.Succeeded),Function.createDelegate(this,this.Failed));
function onQuerySucceeded() {
    fn_appendStatusBar(listItem.get_id());
}
```